# Как создать папку на GitHub и в нее закинуть нужные репозитории?

Tags: git, github

Есть у меня куча репозиториев, которые были созданы во время выполнения лабораторных работ в учебном заведении. Хочу создать папку "Лабы" и туда закинуть все репы. Что то я не разобрался как это сделать, может кто нибудь подскажет?

Comment: GitHub не поддерживает группировку репозиториев по папкам через пути. `/` он заменит на `-`, и скажет об этом до создания репозитория. Посмотрите лучше в сторону тегирования и справочников. Но вы можете создать оторванные ветки под каждую работу и хранить их все в одном репозитории.

Comment: На github нет никаких папок для репозиториев. Есть пользователь - у него будет плоский (без вложенности) список репозиториев, есть организация - у нее тоже плоский список репозиториев. Можно конечно организацию для своих лаб создать, но это как-то чересчур.

Comment: Может просто нормальное README в корне сделать и там сделать разделы в разметке со ссылками на репозитории? )

Comment: обычно в таких случаях делают один общий репозиторий, в котором лежат папки с мелкими проектами